# Create iPhone app without real device

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I can't create provisioning profile, because i dont have real device (with UUID) to add in developer.apple.com -> Devices

I use macincloud.com to run xcode, but while creating provisioning profile, i  get

```
 Failed to create provisioning profile.
 There are no devices registered on your account on the developer website. Plug 
 in and select a device to have Xcode registered it.
```

Client need ios version of cordova app, so i created it using simulator. Now, after developer account registration, i cant upload to app store.

Is it necessary to have iphone for developing apps? Or
Is it necessary to have iPhone for creating provisioning profile?

Thank you

Comment: If you can get someone to give the udid of their phone you can register it manually in the developer portal but it is recommended that you test apps on a real device

Comment: i am from android world, is it security risk for someone, who give me UUID? My client has real device, so we test it on that, but i need to distribute app to him through app store.

Comment: No, it just means that you can build test builds that will run on their phone

Comment: thank you for your time! please answer, i will accept... i found, it is possible with enterprise developer account.. but ask someone is better :)

Comment: You should make an attempt to try and test on an actual device if possible. Although you can do it using a enterprise developer license you shouldn't need to spend the extra money, also I believe you need to give apple a valid reason for requesting enterprise license (I may be wrong). Having his UUID is not a security risk and is the standard way for iOS app testing.

Comment: You _can_ write an iOS app without ever testing on a real device, but to do so is very silly, because the simulator is only a simulator. You don't really know what your app does until you test it on a device.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you should test in real device before submitting the build to app store, because there are chances that some issues/crashes can happen only in real device and not in simulator.

The simulator also frequently substitutes a similar but not identical MacOS X framework or library for an iOS one (because either the team at Apple decided they were close enough, or the team at Apple didn’t have enough time to make the iOS one work like iOS in the simulator). So you can get very different results from OpenGL on iOS vs. the simulator.

But if you are facing time constraints before which you have to submit build to the app store, i would suggest you to at-least go through the below link and verify the check list if any feature that are there in your app which can't be tested in iOS simulator.
https://www.browserstack.com/test-on-iOS-simulator

Also for the time-being you can register any iPhone devices of your friends in the developer portal. Also i don't see any security risks of registering your friend's device in your developer portal, because you can remove him/her from the portal in future.